# Using angular $resource in a factory to display data from nested json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Am new to $resource concepts and am stuck with this piece of code where am just trying to fetch data from a nested json. I have my factory method that is able to fetch the data and is in the response header of the console. But am unable to retrieve it for printing.

```
var f = angular.module("FactModule", ['ngResource']);

f.factory("MenuFactory", function($resource){
    var menuitems =[];
    var menuResource =[];
    var menuResource = $resource("http://localhost:3000/items/:id", {"id":"@mid"},{myupdate:{method: "PUT"}})
    return {
        getMenuItems: function(){                  
         menuitems = menuResource.get();

            console.log(menuitems); 

        },


    }
})
```

Here is my json

```
{
    "items":
            {
                "wsmenuitems": [
                {
                  "code": "AB201",
                  "name": "ABCD",
                  "price": "20.5",
                  "description": "ABCD",
                  "id": 2
                },
                {
                  "code": "901",
                  "name": "XYZ",
                  "price": "25",
                  "description": "XYZ,
                  "id": 5
                }
              ],
               "wsorderitems": [
                {
                  "code": "AB201",
                  "name": "XYA",
                  "price": "20.5",
                  "description": "XYA",
                  "id": 2
                },
                {
                  "code": "901",
                  "name": "PQR",
                  "price": "25",
                  "description": "PQR",
                  "id": 5
                }
              ]
            }
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
c.controller("MenuController", function($scope, MenuFactory){


    $scope.itemsList = MenuFactory.getMenuItems();


});
```

And the HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="menuitem in itemsList">
                    <td>{{$index}}.{{menuitem.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{menuitem.price}}</td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="placeOrder(menuitem)" ng-disabled="itemAdded($index)">Order <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i></button></td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: you are not returning anything from MenuFactory. how are you calling factory?

Comment: tried returning menuitems...but landing up with errors.Accessing it in the controller on a scope variable. Right now my menuitems contains this:Resource {$promise: d, $resolved: false}
$promise
:
d {$$state: {…}}
$resolved
:
true
wsmenuitems
:
(2) [{…}, {…}]
wsorderitems
:
(2) [{…}, {…}]
__proto__
:
Object... I need to access each of this wsmenuitems tried doing .get({id:1}) but does not help

Comment: can you add your controller code along with the question?

Comment: added the controller code

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you are not returning anything from the factory. Refer jsfiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jsengel/aogu66fj/).

```
var f = angular.module("FactModule", ['ngResource']);

f.factory("MenuFactory", function ($resource) {
    var menuitems = [];
    var menuResource = [];
    var menuResource = $resource("http://localhost:3000/items/:id", {
        "id": "@mid"
    }, {
        myupdate: {
            method: "PUT"
        }
    })
    return {
        getMenuItems: function () {
            return menuResource.get().$promise;
        },
    }
})
```

Controller Code

```
MenuFactory.getMenuItems().then((data) => {
    $scope.itemsList = data;
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
})
```